# How do you run Meteor on Windows 8?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, meteor

I've installed Meteor Js by following the instructions but still it won't work. It will create an app but won't run it. It always says : You're not in a Meteor project directory!

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail on what you're doing exactly? Did you do the meteor create app thing? and do you get other errors?

Comment: Word of gentle advice: you can run it on Windows as per Umrem's answer below, but you'll struggle with thing like Meteorite not being supported (yet) etc. I'd recommend a VM if you can, ideally a dual boot.

Comment: I installed meteor in my program files. Then I open my command promtp and go into c:/

Comment: meteor create app1 works
cd app1 works
then when I type metro it says : youre not in a meteor project directory

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just installed Meteor on Windows 8 with success and developing my first application with it.

First you go to http://win.meteor.com/
Second you do what there is written.

Don't forget to reboot and set node.exe to Windows 7 Compatibility.

After that you open cmd.exe

> meteor create sample
>
> cd sample
>
> meteor

Comment: For a more recent version of meteor for Windows, please try: https://github.com/sdarnell/meteor/wiki/Windows

Answer (score 0):

Then find your myapp folder. Just search your computer for it and use that directory location.

For me, it was "cd users/myname/myapp"

Then I could simply "meteor run myapp" and I was fine.